# delete zero after single character using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

i have a string with a single character and a digit, for eg J0. I have to write an expression to remove 0 and keep only that single character.

Comment: regex : `\d` replacement string : empty string.

Comment: I did the same way, but that deletes all. I want to delete only 0 and keep J as it is. eg : J0 to J.

Comment: what do you mean by it deletes all? Could you provide an exact example? or replace 0 with empty string.

Comment: I have used like this name.replaceAll("([A-Z][0-9])","") and my output is blank. what i want is when i give J0 i need J. J0 is my input string.

Comment: Why dont you use just name.replaceAll("([0-9])","") ? [A-Z] will replace chars from A to Z too, that's including J, for instance

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookbehind assertion or capturing group to replace a digit which exists next to an uppercase letter with  empty string.

```
name.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])[0-9]", "");
```

**OR**

```
name.replaceAll("([A-Z])[0-9]", "$1");
```

Comment: or `name.replaceAll("[0-9]$", "");`

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Python using regular expression
With your assumption that you have a string with a single character and a digit, for eg J0

```
>>> import re
>>> x = re.search('(\w)\d', 'j0')
>>> x.groups()
('j',)
>>> x.groups()[0]
'j'
```

You can use the pattern `(\w)\d`